# Google Sign in error 403 - Project marked for deletion

Tags: scala, playframework

I've recently integrated [play-silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette) 4.0.0 with Play 2.5 to handle authentication. I am allowing my users to login with Google and as such am using Silhouette's OAuth2 features. I am redirected to Google's authorization page properly but after pressing allow the app fails with

> 403 - Project marked for deletion

I have enabled the Google+ API in the developer's console and am requesting the scopes "profile email" from the service. I've also deployed the [sample app](https://github.com/sbrunk/play-silhouette-slick-seed) and get the same error. The error codes listed by Google are not much help - anyone have an idea? I've been testing on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue:

1. Create a new project in the Google Developer Console.
2. Enable Google+ API.
3. Create OAuth Credentials.

Perhaps I created the credentials before I enabled the API. Seems a bit silly order would matter. Hope this is helpful to someone else!